# How to use nested promise to call function and get value

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am new to asynchronous call and promise. i want to call three function which calls database. i need to get those results and process it. i use promise for it. it doesn't work as i am thinking i must be not doing right way please suggest. your any answer is appreciated. i am using in NODE JS.
database function seems working it calls database  with three query.

CODE

```
function nested_three_Promise_call_three_function(){
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { return sample(); })
        .then(
        function (val) {
            new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { sample1(); })
                .then(
                function (val) {
                    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { sample2(); })
                        .then({
                            function(val) {
                                /* NEED TO GET VALUE OF ALL SAMPLE,SAMPLE1,SAMPLE 2 FOR FURTHER PROCESS BEFORE SEND TO RESPONSE*/
                                console.log("sample" + sample);
                                console.log("sample1" + sample1);
                                console.log("sample2" + sample2);
                            },
                            function(err){
                                console.log("error inside promise for sample2");
                            }
                        })
                },
                function (err) { 
                    console.log("error inside promise for sample1");
                }
            )
        }, 
        function (error) { 
            console.log("error inside promise for sample1");
        });
}

function sample() {
    console.log("sample called");
    database.query("select * from sample").then(function(result){
        sample  = result;
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("error occured in sample")
    });

}
function sample1() {
     console.log("sample called");
    database.query("select * from sample1").then(function(result){
        sample1  = result;
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("error occured in sample1")
    });
}
function sample2() {
     console.log("sample called");
    database.query("select * from sample2").then(function(result){
        sample2  = result;
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("error occured in sample2")
    });
}
```

Comment: `database.query()` seems to already be returning a promise, so it all seems rather pointless when you could just return that, and do something more like `sample().then(sample1).then(sample2).then( ...`

Comment: @adeneo i appreciate would you please eloborate little more as i am really new to all this.

Comment: `resolve` does not appear to be called at `javascript` at `new Promise(function(resolve, reject){})` at Question? `nested_three_Promise_call_three_function()` would not return a resolved or rejected promise value or reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues there:

1. Your `sampleX` functions don't return anything.
2. Your `sampleX` functions should just return the promises `query` returns.
3. You're creating promises unnecessarily.

So the first thing to do is change:

```
function sample() {
    console.log("sample called");
    database.query("select * from sample").then(function(result){
        sample  = result;
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("error occured in sample")
    });
}
```

to:

```
function sample() {
    console.log("sample called");
    return database.query("select * from sample");
}
```

...and similarly for `sample1` and `sample2`.

If, as suggested by the code in your question, none of the functions uses the result of any of the others, they you can use `Promise.all`:

```
function nested_three_Promise_call_three_function() {
    Promise.all([sample(), sample1(), sample2()])
        .then(function(results) {
            // Use results[0], results[1], and results[2] here
            console.log("From sample:",  results[0]);
            console.log("From sample1:", results[1]);
            console.log("From sample2:", results[2]);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Something went wrong
        });
}

function sample() {
    console.log("sample called");
    return database.query("select * from sample");
}
function sample1() {
    console.log("sample called");
    return database.query("select * from sample1");
}
function sample2() {
    console.log("sample called");
    return database.query("select * from sample2");
}
```

The database calls will run in parallel, and then you'll get the result when they're all done.

---

If they each need the result of the previous one, and you only need the final result at the end, then you chain them; in the below, note that `sample1` and `sample2` now accept an argument:

```
function nested_three_Promise_call_three_function() {
    sample()
        .then(sample1)
        .then(sample2)
        .then(function(result) {
            // `result` is the result from sample2
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Something went wrong
        });
}

function sample() {
    console.log("sample called");
    return database.query("select * from sample");
}
function sample1(arg) {
    console.log("sample called");
    // use arg here
    return database.query("select * from sample1");
}
function sample2(arg) {
    console.log("sample called");
    // use arg here
    return database.query("select * from sample2");
}
```

---

If you need to pass previous results into subsequent functions *and* have all of the results at the end, you probably have several options, but the first thing that comes to mind is just to keep track of them where you make the calls:

```
function nested_three_Promise_call_three_function() {
    let sampleResult, sample1Result;
    sample()
        .then(function(result) {
            sampleResult = result;
            return sample1(result);
        })
        .then(function(result){
            sample1Result = result;
            return sample2(result);
        })
        .then(function(sample2Result) {
            // `sampleResult`, `sample1Result`, and `sample2Result` have the results here
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Something went wrong
        });
}

function sample() {
    console.log("sample called");
    return database.query("select * from sample");
}
function sample1(arg) {
    console.log("sample called");
    // use arg here
    return database.query("select * from sample1");
}
function sample2(arg) {
    console.log("sample called");
    // use arg here
    return database.query("select * from sample2");
}
```

Comment: it complains about Promise.All it doesnt recognize that keyword

Comment: @aka: Case is significant in JavaScript: It's `Promise.all`, not `Promise.All`.

Comment: i have same Promise.All. i copied exact you have posted.

Comment: @aka: You've said `Promise.All` again. It's `Promise.all`. Lowercase `a`. If you're using ES2015 (aka "ES6") promises (built into NodeJS as of v6, possibly earlier), then `Promise.all` will be a function. If you're using something else, you should mention that.

Comment: even = >this symbol isnt recognizing it. i am not using escma 6. would you please suggest how can i rewrite and i am using new Promise does i need to write new Promise.all

Comment: Crowder It works with but  console.log("From sample:",  results[0]);            console.log("From sample1:", results[1]); console.log("From sample2:", Itresults[2]); It return undefined. i debug database query gets call i am using  sequelize after yoiu suggested it's now  return  database.query("select * from sample").then(function(result){
        sample  = result;
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("error occured in sample")
    });

Comment: @aka: The `=>` thing is ES2015 (aka "ES6") syntax; I've updated the answer to stick to ES5. Regarding `Promise.all`: If that's not a function, you're using an outdated version of NodeJS; even v4 has proper Promises. I suggest updating to the latest v4 (or even jumping to v6), and using the built-in promises, not a library.

Comment: thank you so much for saving my life. your solution works. how can i write not using old java version i means not using like "=>"

Comment: @aka: It's JavaScript, not Java. The latest version of NodeJS version 6 (available from http://nodejs.org) has almost complete support for ES2015 (including arrow functions). (I think the only thing missing is ES2015 style modules.)